# Excel sort maintaining equal values in different columns in the same position

Tags: microsoft-excel

Imagine I have the following set of data

```
A               B
AnthonyMorgan   EvelynThomas
JoePatterson    RussellRobinson
JohnAnderson    ChristopherMiller
CarolynMorris   RyanStewart
DorisKing       SarahPrice
AlanJohnson     MarilynHall
JonathanHall    EricCooper
AndreaPowell    GregorySimmons
PaulaCooper     JackRussell
AndrewPeterson  SeanEvans
JohnWilliams    JudyBell
LillianLewis    JohnWilliams
SteveRoberts    LillianLewis
MatthewGray     SteveRoberts
ChristinaClark  MatthewGray
                PeterAllen
                SharonHill
                MaryTurner
                DorisGonzales
                VictorWhite
                JoanFoster
                ChristinaClark
                RubyBryant
                RogerColeman
                JosephLong
                AndrewPeterson
```

I would like to sort, imagine by column `A` so that same values in different columns are kept together. The final result would be:

```
A                   B
AlanJohnson 
AndreaPowell    
AndrewPeterson      AndrewPeterson
AnthonyMorgan   
CarolynMorris   
ChristinaClark      ChristinaClark
                    ChristopherMiller
                    DorisGonzales
DorisKing   
                    EricCooper
                    EvelynThomas
                    GregorySimmons
                    JackRussell
                    JoanFoster
JoePatterson    
JohnAnderson    
JohnWilliams        JohnWilliams
JonathanHall    
                    JosephLong
                    JudyBell
LillianLewis        LillianLewis
                    MarilynHall
                    MaryTurner
MatthewGray         MatthewGray
PaulaCooper 
                    PeterAllen
                    RogerColeman
                    RubyBryant
                    RussellRobinson
                    RyanStewart
                    SarahPrice
                    SeanEvans
                    SharonHill
SteveRoberts        SteveRoberts
                    VictorWhite
```

Any idea?

Comment: My first suggestion is that you describe your question accurately.  It looks to me like you want the data sorted by Column A *and* Column B.  Aside from what I can see in your example, I don't know what "same values in different columns are kept together" means.

Comment: Why did *DorisKing* get moved from column **A** to column **B** ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this macro:

```
Sub Interleaver()
    Dim nA As Long, nB As Long
    Dim rc As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    rc = Rows.Count
    nA = Cells(rc, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    nB = Cells(rc, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & nA).Copy Range("C1")
    Range("B1:B" & nB).Copy Range("C" & nA + 1)

    For i = 1 To nA + nB
        If i <= nA Then
            Cells(i, "D") = "A"
        Else
            Cells(i, "D") = "B"
        End If
    Next i

    Range("C1:D" & nA + nB).Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Range("A1:A" & nA).Clear
    Range("B1:B" & nB).Clear
    j = 2

    If Range("D1").Value = "A" Then
        Cells(1, "A") = Cells(1, "C")
    Else
        Cells(1, "B") = Cells(1, "C")
    End If

    For i = 2 To nA + nB
        If Cells(i, "C") = Cells(i - 1, "C") Then
            j = j - 1
            Range("A" & j & ":B" & j) = Cells(i, "C")
            j = j + 1
        Else
            If Cells(i, "D").Value = "A" Then
                Cells(j, "A") = Cells(i, "C")
            Else
                Cells(j, "B") = Cells(i, "C")
            End If
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It will produce:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary. Thanks. That solved my initial problem. At the end, I have more than two columns. Will try to understand your code to try to adjust it to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to do it. Try this:
  - merge your data in one range remembering original location (e.g. Copy your first column to a new sheet and fill "1" in the next column, copy the second column below first one and fill "10" in the second column for this set of data).
  - insert a pivot table, column labels should be your first column and ask for sum of second column ( now you have your unique values sorted alphabetically, in second column 1 or 10 if name occurred only in one column or 11 if it present in both).
  - supposing that your data in pivot table starts in A5, enter this in C5: `=if(mod(b5,2)=1,a5,"")` and this one in d5: `=if(b5>9,a5,"")`

Answer (score 0):

Another workflow would be as follows. Note that it is performed manually, since I'm not aware of any excel functions that does what you are looking for. Another option would be to use Macro or VBA to automate the workflow suggested below.

Image 1 shows initial example data:

[image: Initial]

Start by sorting wach coloumn separately. Keep that sorting doesn't affect the other coloumn.Than add another coloumn to aid the process, and write an index-match function to find matchs in for each A coloumn entry from the B coloumn:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$10,MATCH(A2,$C$1:$C$10,0),1)
```

Image 2 shows the results of this stage:

[image: Indexing]

Now cut and paste the B coloumn to aviod being adjacent to NA values. That is two cells down in the example. Afterwards cut and paste col A and the aiding coloumn to match entries with the B coloumn. See image below:

[image: Iterations]

Iterate this phase untill finished. Remember to start with col B and than match col A and the INDEX col (aiding coloumn). Finally remove the INDEX column and you are done.

[image: Almost Done]

[image: DONE!]

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the dataset is too big. It is only a viable solution to small datasets

Comment: Thoght so, might worth to use VBA or macro to automate that workflow. That's beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking for is a full outer join treating the two columns as separate tables.

As far as I am aware, this is not possible in native Excel even with the help of the Power Query plugin.

You *can* achieve the results **IF** the longer table encompass all of the entries in the shorter table but your example shows that not to be the case.

What you can do is to append the two columns and then dedup, that is easy enough. You could also add a count column so that you could see how many copies of the same name existed in the original data. Let me know if you want to do that.

UPDATE: As I anticipated, you can do this with Microsoft Access. To do so, you first need to have the two columns as separate tables. You then have to create TWO joins between the tables, a left outer join and a right outer join. Once you've created those relationships, you can do a simple query to select the single column from each table. That's it.

You can leave your original data in Excel if you want to and simply link to it as long as you split the two columns into separate tables.